# Sheets.Columns to hide columns

Tags: excel, vba

I can hide columns by using the following code:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Columns("G:K").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```

Now, I have the last column in number, not letter.

```
last_column= Sheets(1).UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
```

I guess I could convert the last_column to the corresponding letter and use the first code to hide columns. Is there a more direct way of doing it without resorting to converting number to letter?

I have tried different variations to replace "G:K" with numbers with no avail.

Comment: What is your goal? Hiding all used columns? Please clarify.

Comment: No. Just hide column G to the last column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try:**

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    .Range(.Columns("G"), .Columns(last_column)).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

Determine intStartCol and intEndCol as the numbers of your first and last columns, then you can hide by:

```
With Sheets(1)
    .Range(.Columns(intStartCol),.Columns(intEndCol)).Hidden = True
end with
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try `Resize`.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
  .Columns("G").Resize(, last_column - 6).Hidden = True
End With
```